# arithmetic operation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to perform addition in javascript. below is my code :

```js
function myfunc(size){ 
    var m = parseInt(size)+5;
    alert(m );
```

When i use 'alert',it works perfectly.. but i want to use sweet alert and it is not display anything via sweet alert. when i do:

```js
function myfunc(size){ 
    sweetAlert(size );
```

it does display the size using the code above. the problem is, it doesn't work when i try to perform the addition. why is it so?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
import swal from "sweetalert";

function myfunc(size) {
  var m = parseInt(size) + 5;
  swal(String(m));
}

myfunc("6");
```

Comment: That's great. Can you mark it as accepted answer?